# How to tell if forms launched as child window

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form which has a button to launch a new form (to add new data, that can be selected in the parent window).
This child form can also be viewed as a parent window, what I want to do is add a Close button to this window but should only be visible if its a child window.

Does anyone know how I can detect if the window is a child window in VBA for MS Access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use OpenArgs argument of the [OpenForm method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa141520%28v=office.10%29.aspx) to pass a value to the form when it is opened as a child. Checking `Me.OpenArgs` will then give you the information you require.